# Devolver 5 numeros aleatorios de un array sin repetir

Tags: javascript

Hola quiero devolver  5 numeros aleatorios diferentes de un array javascript sin que estos se repitan.

Tengo el siguiente script pero no se como generar solo 5.

```
var numbers = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59'];
var numero = numbers.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5});
return numero;
```

Necesito devolver 5 numeros sin que se repitan

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar:

```js
var numbers = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59'];

const randomNumbers = []

const NUMBERS_LENGTH = numbers.length

// agregando aleatorios a randomNumbers
while(randomNumbers.length < 5) {
  const randomIndex = getRandom()
  if (!checkNotRepeat(numbers[randomIndex], randomNumbers))
    randomNumbers.push(numbers[randomIndex])
}

// obteniendo aleatorios en rango
function getRandom() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * NUMBERS_LENGTH)
}

// checkeando por no repetidos
function checkNotRepeat(current, validNumbers) {
  return validNumbers.includes(current)
}

console.log(randomNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uso un arreglo y verifico si ya tengo 10 numero generados `(randoms.length < 10)` y si no lo es entonces voy agregando los numeros aleatoreos Math.random() en mi arreglo `randoms`

```js
let randoms = [];
while (randoms.length < 10) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10));
  if (randoms.indexOf(random) == -1) {
    randoms.push(random);
  }
}
console.log(randoms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Así es como lo haría:`let n = ~~(Math.random()*numbers.length);` devuelve un numero aleatorio entre 0 y `numbers.length`. Utilizo `~~` como `Math.floor`

```js
let numbers = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59'];
//un array para guardar los 5 elementos aleatorios
let nuevoArray = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){//5: necesito 5 números
  let n = ~~(Math.random()*numbers.length);
  // ponlo en el nuevo array
  nuevoArray.push(numbers[n]);
  // bórralo de numbers
  numbers.splice(numbers[n], 1);
}

console.log(nuevoArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir una **función que devuelve de forma desordenada elementos de un array sin repetir**. En este caso recibe dos argumentos, el primero el array de elementos. El segundo, es opcional y permite obtener un array con menos elementos que el array original si se requiere.

```js
function getRandomSort(arr, number_of_elements)
{
    // Check and fix number_of_elements value
    if (number_of_elements === undefined
        || number_of_elements > arr.length) {
        number_of_elements = arr.length
    }

    let result = [];
    while (result.length < number_of_elements) {
        // Get a position to fetch an element
        let position = Math.floor(Math.random() * number_of_elements);

        // Check the contents of the array before push a new element
        if (result.indexOf(arr[position]) === -1) {
            result.push(arr[position]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Tests
var numbers = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08'];

console.log('Get all elements:');
console.log(getRandomSort(numbers));
console.log('---------------------------\n');

let number_of_elements = 5;
console.log(`Get ${number_of_elements} elements: `);
console.log(getRandomSort(numbers, number_of_elements));
```

Posible resultado (en la consola del navegador):

```
Get all elements:
(9) ["05", "03", "04", "08", "02", "07", "01", "06", "00"]
---------------------------

Get 5 elements: 
(5) ["02", "00", "01", "03", "04"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes eliminar de la matriz el elemento que se ha obtenido con el método Splice()

```
 var numbers = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59'];

 for (var i =0; i < 5; i++){
 console.log(numbers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length), 1));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59'];
    
var numero = numbers.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5});
    
const fiveNumber = numero.splice(0,5)
```

Comment: Procura agregar más detalles a tu respuesta: si bien puede ser útil al OP, necesitas detallar tu respuesta para que otros usuarios en un futuro puedan comprender _por qué_ funciona esto. Lee [answer].